# Regarding Createjs android and window phone support

Tags: touch-event, createjs

Hi I am making my project with Create js .. I used touch function in my project. I have an image that is scrolled automatically and with the touch we can change its direction, but unfortunately it doesn't react properly on the android and windows phone, but works well on ipad and pc.. any help,,,  please help how can I achieve same behavior over android and windows phone., thanks in advance

Comment: You have to be more specific. What do you mean by "doesn't react properly" ? What actually happens? Can you maybe post some screenshots?

Comment: Hi sorry i replied late. was on off. u can see my another question that helps to understand my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335111/createjs-canvass-shape-losses-its-co-ordinates-on-windows-phone .... @Illidanek